# I am curious about applying my coursework from Masters program towards Doctoral in Economics in the US

Tags: phd, economics

I earned a Master's degree in Analytics (one of the newer and popular graduate school majors) and am considering going back to school for Ph.D. in Economics. I am curious if Universities in the US with doctoral programs in Economics accept coursework from Master's degree to be applied towards Ph.D. program? It probably varies by universities as they set their own policies, so if anyone with experience can share specific cases that would be helpful.

I am planning on applying to the top tier as well other schools with Econ program in the United States and maybe Oxford or LSE in the U.K.

There's some overlap with the courses, especially the stats courses and time series, econometrics which is the focus that I intend to pursue my Ph.D.

Comment: I think this is specific enough to answer. I like how @aeismail has dealt with it. The question could perhaps be rephrased to ask how much policies vary or how to find out this information.

Comment: The question has been rephrased. I am looking for instances for when people have successfully transferred coursework.

Answer (score 3):

**There is no uniform policy in the US. You must check with each program you are interested in.**

Graduate departments are generally give broad latitude in accepting coursework from other schools. Some may choose to give either credit or merely placement; some may offer both or neither. Some may require what they consider “core” courses to be retaken but allow electives to count. Other schools may have a limit on the number of transfer credits they will accept. There are simply too many variations, so direct questions to the graduate admissions officer or director of graduate studies (or the equivalent( is your best option.

As @Dawn has suggested in the comments below, it is indeed worth noting that one should likely not ignore the possibility of taking the core classes required to pass the department's qualification examinations, and most advisors will encourage you to do exactly that.

Comment: Yes, this is technically correct. However, you should also note that most top Economics programs will have qualifying exams at the end of the first year. It is likely more difficult to pass these exams if you have not taken a recent course in the topic or even if the course you took as a Master's student uses a different book. The qualifying exam really limits the practicality of transferring in courses and I would rarely recommend the strategy.